# Capturing TDie Message of Child Job in Parent Job using tLogCatcher

Tags: talend

I have a Parent Job triggering a Child Job on Iterate.

There are tDie defined inside the child job with appropriate message. Upon error in Child Job the execution is failing which is ideal but the tLogCatcher is not catching the error message.

Error message is marked Null. tLogCatcher is enabled for all error catching.

Is there a scope issue that since the error happened in Child hence Parent doesnt have all info. How to make the child send back all the tDie encountered for the tLogCatcher to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In the child job, don't put any tLogCatcher.

In the parent job, put tLogCatcher and connect it with tLog to print error message.

In the parent job, when you call the child job using tRunJob component, check the "Die on error" setting.

With these settings, whatever error happens in child job, will be logged in parent job tLogCatcher.